# how to select multiple columns from dataframe and dump to list in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i have a dataframe with multiple columns, and I need to select 2 of them and dump them to a list, and i've tried the following :

```
df.show()
+------------------------------------+---------------+---------------+
|email_address                       |topic          |user_id        |
+------------------------------------+---------------+---------------+
|xyz@test.com                        |hello_world    |xyz123         |
+------------------------------------+---------------+---------------+
|lmn@test.com                        |hello_kitty    |lmn456         |
+------------------------------------+---------------+---------------+
```

the result I need is a list of tuples:

```
[(xyz@test.com, xyz123), (lmn@test.com, lmn456)]
```

the way I tried:

```
tuples = df.select(col('email_address'), col('topic')).rdd.flatMap(lambda x, y: list(x, y)).collect()
```

and it throw errors:

```
Py4JJavaError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-4050677552755250> in <module>()

--> 114 tuples = df.select(col('email_address'), col('topic')).rdd.flatMap(lambda x, y: list(x, y)).collect()
    115 
    116 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py in collect(self)
    829         # Default path used in OSS Spark / for non-credential passthrough clusters:
    830         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
--> 831             sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
    832         return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, self._jrdd_deserializer))
    833 

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
```

how to fix it?

Comment: function in flatMap takes only one argument. for your task, use a list comprehension should be enough. `tuples = [ (r.email_address, r.user_id) for r in df.select('email_address', 'user_id').collect() ]`

Comment: or `tuples = [*map(tuple, df.select('email_address', 'user_id').collect())]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `map` for that:

```
tuples = df.select(col('email_address'), col('topic')) \
           .rdd \
           .map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1])) \
           .collect()

print(tuples)

# output
[('xyz@test.com', 'hello_world'), ('lmn@test.com', 'hello_kitty')]
```

Another way is to collect rows for DataFrame and then loop to get values:

```
rows = df.select(col('email_address'), col('topic')).collect()

tuples = [(r.email_address, r.topic) for r in rows]
print(tuples)

# output
[('xyz@test.com', 'hello_world'), ('lmn@test.com', 'hello_kitty')]
```